# ssh2_connect causes Error 324 (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE):

Tags: php, linux, ssh, lampp

While trying to list the files present in a remote sftp location using php, I get this error:

> Error 324 (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE):

The server closed the connection without sending any data. On my another lamp server the same code works fine. Please point where I am missing something if you can help please. Thanks in advance.

```
function listBuildFiles() {

global $sftp_host, $sftp_username, $sftp_password, $sftp_path;
$connection = ssh2_connect($sftp_host);
// Authenticate
if (!ssh2_auth_password($connection, $sftp_username, $sftp_password)) {
    throw new Exception('Unable to connect.');
}

// Create our SFTP resource
if (!$sftp = ssh2_sftp($connection)) {
    throw new Exception('Unable to create SFTP connection.');
}

/**
 * Now that we have our SFTP resource, we can open a directory resource
 * to get us a list of files. Here we will use the $sftp resource in
 * our address string as I previously mentioned since our ssh2://
 * protocol allows it.
 */
$files = array();
$dirHandle = opendir("ssh2.sftp://$sftp$sftp_path");
    $i=0;
// Properly scan through the directory for files, ignoring directory indexes (. & ..)
while (false !== ($file = readdir($dirHandle))) {
    if ($file != '.' && $file != '..') {
        $files[$i] = $file;
        $i++;
    }
}

echo '<select name="buildName">';
echo '<option>Please Select a build</option>';
foreach ($files as $filename) {
      echo "<option value=\"$filename\">$filename</option>";
    }
echo '</select>';
ssh2_exec($connection, "exit");
```

Thanks,
Ujjwal

Comment: Did you take a look at your php/apache logs?

Comment: And have you looked at your sshd log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With [phpseclib, a pure PHP SFTP implementation](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/), you can see the full logs of what's going on.  Example:

```
<?php
include('Net/SFTP.php');

define('NET_SSH2_LOGGING', NET_SSH2_LOG_COMPLEX);

$sftp = new Net_SFTP('www.domain.tld');
if (!$sftp->login('username', 'password')) {
    exit('Login Failed');
}

// puts a three-byte file named filename.remote on the SFTP server
$sftp->put('filename.remote', 'xxx');

echo $ssh->getLog();
print_r($ssh->getErrors());
?>
```

The developer of phpseclib is pretty proactive about providing support too so if you can't figure it out from the logs or error messages (s)he probably can.

Answer (score 1):

Just to make sure there is no problem on the server side you can open a console and try a raw ssh connection in verbose mode:

```
ssh -v youruser@yourhost.com
```

this traces all the interactions between server and client, maybe gives you some clue from the server side.